# Generating cluster counts for map rendering using PostGIS

Tags: postgis

Each row in my table (1m+ rows and growing) has a field  `location` containing the lat/lng Point coordinate. These points are rendered in a map.

At higher zoom levels I am using Supercluster to cluster points server-side ahead of rendering. This works nicely as I can rely on the WHERE clause `location && ST_MakeEnvelope(...)` to limit the scope to the bounding box corresponding to the zoom level.

At lower zoom levels, however, this approach cannot be efficient. At zoom level 0, for example, the query returns every point before Supercluster gets to do its thing.

What is the best strategy for generating/aggregating counts at these lower zoom levels?

Is there perhaps a clever query that aggregates by converting the Point to a Tile coordinate?

I am using PostGIS.

Comment: what language are you using for server side scripting

Comment: i'm using nodejs